# Is the Weil restriction of an elliptic curve self-dual?

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

$\DeclareMathOperator\res{res}$Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$, and let $$p\equiv 1\pmod 3$$
be a prime split in $K$. Assume that
$$p=\omega*\overline\omega,\quad\text{where}\quad\omega\equiv 1\pmod 3.$$ Let
$$E:y^2=x^3+\omega^2/4$$
be the elliptic curve with CM by $\mathcal{O}_K$, and let $$\overline{E}:y^2=x^3+\overline\omega^2/4.$$
Then we have an abelian variety
$$A=\res_{K/\mathbb{Q}}E=\res_{K/\mathbb{Q}}\overline{E}$$ that is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, and we also have that
$$A_K=E\times\overline{E}.$$
My question: Is the abelian variety $A$ self-dual?